# Solve the dif. eq. $y'=\frac{(3x+y^3-1)^2}{y^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the dif. eq. $$y'=\frac{(3x+y^3-1)^2}{y^2}$$

I see that this equation isn't exact. 
Is there exist any integrating factor that can apply, to solve it?
I tried to find it using the methodology, but i cannot.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y'=\frac{(3x+y^3-1)^2}{y^2}$$

Multiply both sides by $y^2$ and consider the substitution

$$u(x)=3x+y(x)^3-1\implies u'=3+3y^2y'\implies y^2y'=\frac{u'-3}3$$

Then the ODE is transformed to the separable equation,

$$\frac{u'-3}3=u^2\implies u'=3u^2+3$$

Comment: Thanks, I get it!!

Answer (score 0):

Let
 $$y^3 +3x -1= t$$
to get 
$$\frac{dt}{dx} = 3{y^2} y^{\prime}+3$$
Or equivalently
$${y^2}{y^{\prime}} = \frac{{t^{\prime}}-3}{3}$$
Just plug in these values and you will get
$$\frac{{t^{\prime}}}{1+t^2}=3$$
Which results in 
$${{tan}^{-1}}(3x+y^3-1)=3x + C$$

Comment: Almost correctly, you need the term 1/2 on the left side

Comment: Where?? I didn't see it

Comment: In original equation \(3x+y^3−1\) is squared. So you need to take derivative of $t^2$ giving $2t$